# Kotlin - from a list of Maps, to a map grouped by key

Tags: kotlin

I have a `List<Map<Branch,Pair<String, Any>>>` that I would like to convert in a single `Map<Branch,List<Pair<String, Any>>>` .

So if I have an initial list with simply 2 elements :

List

```
1. branch1 -> Pair(key1,value1)

   branch2 -> Pair(key2,value2)


2. branch1 -> Pair(key1a,value1a)
```

I want to end up with :

Map

```
branch1 -> Pair(key1,value1)

           Pair(key1a,value1a)

branch2 -> Pair(key2,value2)
```

so a kind of groupBy, using all the values of the keys in the initially nested maps..

I have tried with

```
list.groupBy{it-> it.keys.first()}
```

but obviously it doesn't work, as it uses only the first key. I want the same, but using all keys as individual values.

What is the most idiomatic way of doing this in Kotlin ? I have an ugly looking working version in Java, but I am quite sure Kotlin has a nice way of doing it.. it's just that I am not finding it so far !

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following:

```
val result =
    listOfMaps.asSequence()
        .flatMap {
          it.asSequence()
        }.groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
```

will give you the `result` of type `Map<Branch,List<Pair<String, Any>>>` with the contents you requested.

Comment: Thanks, it works. FYI I've made the change here : https://github.com/societe-generale/github-crawler/blob/fe93772138fe6c4f5a759771215a2bc034205b06/github-crawler-core/src/main/kotlin/com/societegenerale/githubcrawler/RepositoryEnricher.kt#L126-L133

Comment: well... you could have said, that it actually ends up in a `Map<Branch, Map<String, Any>>`... that `.mapValues` could also already be simplified to: `.mapValues { it.value.toMap() }`

Answer (score 8):

```
val list: List<Map<Branch, Pair<String, Any>>> = listOf() 
val map = list
    .flatMap { it.entries }
    .groupBy { it.key }
    .mapValues { entry -> entry.value.map { it.value } }
```

Answer (score 4):

Everyone else is using `flatMap`, but you can also consider using `fold`, which is a common operation for reducing a larger collection into a smaller one. (For example, you can `fold` a list of integers into a single sum; here, a list of maps into a single map).

Perhaps others will find this easier to read than the `flatMap` versions above:

```kotlin
val listOfMaps: List<Map<Key, Value>> = ...

val mergedMaps: Map<Key, List<Value>> = 
  listOfMaps
    .fold(mutableMapOf()) { acc, curr ->
      curr.forEach { entry -> acc.merge(entry.key, listOf(entry.value)) { new, old -> new + old } }
      acc
    }
```

What the above code is doing:

- Create a new, empty map. This will be `acc` (that is, the accumulator).
- Iterate through our list of maps.
- Work on one map (`curr`) at a time.
- For the current map, run over each of its key/value pairs.
- For each key/value, call `merge` on `acc`, passing in a list of size one (wrapping the value). If nothing is associated with the key yet, that list is added; otherwise, it is appended to the list already there.
- Return the accumulating map, so it's used again in the next step.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to write this.

```
data class Branch(val name: String)
data class Key(val name: String)
data class Value(val name: String)


val sharedBranch = Branch("1")
val listOfMaps: List<Map<Branch, Pair<Key, Value>>> = listOf(
        mapOf(sharedBranch to Pair(Key("1"), Value("1")),
                Branch("2") to Pair(Key("2"), Value("2"))),
        mapOf(sharedBranch to Pair(Key("1a"), Value("1a")))
)

val mapValues: Map<Branch, List<Pair<Key, Value>>> = listOfMaps.asSequence()
        .flatMap { map -> map.entries.asSequence() }
        .groupBy(Map.Entry<Branch, Pair<Key, Value>>::key)
        .mapValues { it.value.map(Map.Entry<Branch, Pair<Key, Value>>::value) }

println(mapValues)
```

Is it appliable for your needs?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, Kotlin's `Map` and `MutableMap` interfaces do not contain this method

Comment: On the JVM, this is legal Kotlin: `val map = mutableMapOf(1 to "a", 2 to "b"); map.merge(1, "c") { v0, v1 -> v0 + v1}`

Comment: @TimCastelijns I tried to write it, but `merge` is not a good fit, you can do it with `compute`. It's not a great win over `groupBy` solutions, though. `val result = mutableMapOf<Branch, MutableList<Pair<String, Any>>>(); listOfMaps.forEach { map -> map.forEach { k, v -> result.compute(k) { _, v0 -> v0?.also { it.add(v) } ?: mutableListOf(v) } } }`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, but it is if you have mutable map returned to you as an argument. otherwise you are forced to create an excessive copy.
I didn't write is is illegal, I have wrote that `Kotlin's Map` interface does not have this method

Comment: My code makes zero copies, as opposed to yours. Both `groupBy` and `mapValues` return a new map.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, `fun doSmth(first: Map<Any, Any>, second: Map<Any, Any>) { ...}` - try to do it here

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, also, sequences are lazy

Comment: 1. `groupBy` does not return a lazy sequence. 2. My code returns a new map (zero copying, just a single map that is the result). Your code creates a temporary map, then creates the map it will return.

Comment: please read what I have wrote about copy once more.
you have `MutableMap` because you have declared `mutableMapOf`. what are you going to do if you have `Map`?

Comment: You seem to have confused something fundamental here. What you're _getting_ is a `List<Map<Key, Value>>`. What you're _returning_ is a `Map<Key, List<Value>>`. Clearly, you're creating a new map to return. Doesn't matter whether the input is mutable or immutable. And remember: `MutableMap` is a subtype of `Map`.

Comment: big debate here.. for the record, what @AndreyIlyunin suggested works in my case, so thanks. But I accepted Roland 's answer, as it is shorter

Answer (score 1):

Surprised nobody has mentioned the [associate](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/associate.html) function.

```kotlin
val listy: List<Map<String, Int>> = 
listOf(mapOf("A" to 1, "B" to 2), mapOf("C" to 3, "D" to 4))
 
val flattened = listy
  .flatMap { it.asSequence() }
  .associate { it.key to it.value }

println(flattened)
```

will print out `{A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4}`

Answer (score 0):

Extract it to an extension function

```
private fun <K, V> List<Map<K, V>>.group(): Map<K, List<V>> =
        asSequence().flatMap { it.asSequence() }.groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
```

Use it like so:

```
val list = yourListOfMaps
val grouped = list.group()
```