# kotlin reduce list of map to a single map

Tags: kotlin

How do I reduce reduce

```
val res = [{a=3}, {a=2, c=1}]
```

Into

```
val res = [{a=5,c=1}]` //or 

val res = {a=5, c=1}
```

?

I tried the groupBy function but that doesn't give me the desired result. I want to sump up the values of same keys.

Comment: you can reduce using Map.putAll. You're not saying how you want to resolve conflicts, though

Comment: @njzk2 edited the question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53433108/kotlin-from-a-list-of-maps-to-a-map-grouped-by-key

Comment: `res` is a list of maps to begin with? Kotlin doesn’t have collection literals so your code as shown can’t be real.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You can use `listOf(mapOf('a' to 3), mapOf('a' to 2, 'c' to 1))`, which results in `[{a=3}, {a=2, c=1}]` when printed.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Ik I have listOf(... ) in my code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fold` operator

For example

```kotlin
val list = listOf(mapOf("a" to 3), mapOf("a" to 2, "c" to 1))

val res = list.fold(mutableMapOf<String, Int>()) { acc, v ->
    v.forEach { (key, value) ->
        if (acc.contains(key)) {
            acc[key] = acc[key]!! + value
        } else {
            acc[key] = value
        }
    }
    acc
}
```

Or by `reduce` operator:

```kotlin
val res = list.reduce { acc, map ->
    val res = acc.toMutableMap()
    map.forEach { (key, value) ->
        res[key] = res.getOrDefault(key, 0) + value
    }
    res
}
```

Or `groupBy` and `sumBy` operators

```kotlin
val res = list.flatMap { it.entries }
        .groupBy { it.key }
        .mapValues { it.value.sumBy { v -> v.value } }
```

Answer (score 0):

To have conflicting values summed, you can use `x.asSequence().flatMap { it.asSequence() }.groupBy { it.key }.mapValues { it.value.asSequence().map { it.value }.sum() }`, resulting in `{a=5, c=1}`.

Comment: This doesn’t handle conflicts.

Comment: I edited the question. I want the values with same key to be summed

Comment: @max_mal I have fixed my answer to sum conflicting keys.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it will be to iterate over a list. Like this:

```
val input = listOf(
    mapOf(
        "a" to 2
    ),
    mapOf(
        "a" to 3,
        "c" to 1
    )
)

val result = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
input.forEach { map ->
    map.forEach { (key, value) ->
        result[key] = result.getOrElse(key, { 0 }) + value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already a bunch of answers to the actual problem in the question, but if those maps are counts of items, and you're generating them yourself, you might want to create [Grouping](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-grouping/)s instead

```
val source = listOf(listOf('a', 'a', 'a'), listOf('a', 'a', 'c'))
// creating a grouping for each list, using each item as its own key
val grouped = source.map { it.groupingBy { it } }
```

And then you can use [eachCountTo](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/each-count-to.html) and a map to build up counts for each key

```
val counts = grouped.fold(mutableMapOf<Char, Int>()) { countMap, grouping ->
    grouping.eachCountTo(countMap)
    countMap
}
print(counts)

>> {a=5, c=1}
```

Good to know it exists, anyway!